# Chinese Barcode Printer and Linux

Tags: php, linux, printing, linux-device-driver, barcode-printing

I have bought a chinese barcode printer GP-3150TIN. It haven't linux drivers. On Windows I'm printing directly to LPT using printers own markup language. But printer connected to PC via USB and to print directly to LPT I had to use such nasty hack:

```
+ Create a share for the USB printer
+ net use LPT5 \\COMPUTERNAME\SHARENAME /PERSISTENT:YES
```

After that I could print the way like this

```
copy con LPT5
...
Ctrl+Z, Enter
```

I suspect that this way of printing is via some generic interface, and it realized on linux too. Maybe I'm wrong.

Please help me to print in linux. Perfectly from PHP, could be from bash. In the worst way at least print on Windows avoiding that nasty hack and printing like

```
copy con USB0001
...
Ctrl+Z, Enter
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: My printer supports Ethernet connection. That's why I have found the best way of printing for me via netcat. It looks like:

echo "Hello \n" | nc -w 1 <printer's IP> <port>.

Fast, no delays, can place printer everywhere I want and can print from PHP via shell_exec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the steps outlined in this [blog post](http://mike.bitrevision.com/blog/2015-03-getting-a-usb-receipt-printer-working-on-linux). When you have identified the lpX device, you could use it like `cat filename > /dev/usb/lpX`. The links also shows a php example.